# Should we use CScript.exe or WScript.exe to run .vbs files?

Tags: vbscript, wsh

VBScript (.vbs) files can be run using either cscript.exe or wscript.exe.

What's the difference between these two options?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One major difference is that `cscript` runs within a console, `wscript` does not.

If you want console-like output, use `cscript`. In that mode, printing will result in output to the console. That same printing in `wscript` send its output to dialog boxes:

```
wscript.echo "hello"
```

Answer (score 3):

With cscript, it displays the info in a cmd window, which will not stop the script. while using Hscript will get a info pop up which halts the script